# Using before CSS, add circle in the background

Tags: html, css, swiper.js

I want to add a circle behind the navigation button. But i am unable to achieve it. I am using Swiper.

These are some snapshots when i am positioning circle below the navigation arrow.

[image][image][image]

As you can see, when i am adjusting margin-left of ::before, the background circle goes above of the navigation button. I am using pseudo::before css to create circle. But i can't achieve it. This is my css work. Please check it, and let me know, where am i doing wrong?

```css
.content .swiper-button-next {
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 62px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    z-index: 4 !important;
    position: absolute;
}

.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-white{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%…2L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
}

.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
    top: 50%;
    width: 27px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 27px 44px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.content .swiper-button-next:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: -53px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: -2;
    position: relative;
    background: #080808;
}
```

```html
<div class="content swiper-container-horizontal swiper-container-free-mode">
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would just "reverse" it. Add the circle to the element and the background image to the `:before` element.

Comment: I have modified the question. I did not get a solution till now. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.swiper-button-next:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #060606;
  margin-left: -53px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 62px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: -13px;
  z-index: 4 !important;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%…2L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  top: 50%;
  width: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: 27px 44px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.arrow{ width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 31px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.3;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"><div class="arrow">❯<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the `z-index` from the `.swiper-button-next` div will solve the issue.

```css
.swiper-button-next:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #060606;
  margin-left: -53px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 62px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/C/n/U/D/t/D/transparent-arrow-hi.png);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  top: 50%;
  width: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: 27px 44px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place the symbol in the `content` property of the `pseudoelement`:

```css
.swiper-button-next {
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 62px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    z-index: 4 !important;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
    top: 50%;
    width: 27px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.swiper-button-next:before {
    content: '>';
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #060606;
    margin-left: -53px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: -2;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 50px; /* vertically center the symbol */
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
```

Comment: but `.swiper-button-next` class has background image which is equivalent to ">".

Answer (score 0):

check the snippet please , i have changed your code little bit

```css
.swiper-button-next::before {
    background-image: url("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/arrow-30-xxl.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px 29px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: relative;
    right: -15px;
    width: 22px;
    z-index: -2;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: -13px;
  z-index: 4 !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #060606;
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
```